# displaying tables in SQlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm going through Python+SQlite tutorial. I'm creating tables, adding information, deleting it etc. The only way I can check how the table looks like is in cmd and it really doesn't look nice and readible. What I mean is that the content is fine, but the way the table is displayed isn't. Is there any way, maybe, some additional program to download or sth, that I can see my table like it's an actual TABLE and not some: Name | Age | Job ?

Comment: A tool that can do much more than just display the contents of an SQLite DB: http://sqlitebrowser.org

Comment: Take a look at this question, there is a list of sqlite GUIs and their pros and cons:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend

Answer (score 1):

You can set the display mode to 'column' for a slightly more readable printout of your data.

```
.mode column
SELECT * FROM table;
```

If you'd like to view a readable version in a text file:

```
.mode column
.headers on
.output my_data.txt
SELECT * FROM table;
.exit

open my_data.txt
```

Other modes:

```
.mode MODE ?TABLE?   Set output mode where MODE is one of:
                     csv      Comma-separated values
                     column   Left-aligned columns.  (See .width)
                     html     HTML <table> code
                     insert   SQL insert statements for TABLE
                     line     One value per line
                     list     Values delimited by .separator string
                     tabs     Tab-separated values
                     tcl      TCL list elements
```